# Adding string variables C++

Tags: c++, string, pointers

Why can't we add two C-strings in C++? This is what I know, please correct me, and add to it.

Is it because the '+' operator is not overloaded to do the operation. The compiler essentially interprets the variable name as a pointer. Since, we can not add two pointers, so we can't add two string variables like this: str = str + "str"?

Comment: Because a `const char []` is a `const char []` and a `std::string` is  the standard string in C++.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/13507/

Comment: Why would you not use the string library? You can certainly concatenate (not add) strings. But it seems you're mixing C++ strings with C strings. In C++ strings are not just pointers/arrays but a class.

Comment: "_Since, we can not add two pointers, so we can't add two string variables_" Well, we can subtract one pointer from another, but it does not mean that we can subtract entities they point to.

Comment: What do you mean by "string"? If you mean the standard library class of that name, then you *can* add strings.

Comment: My Bad for not being clear here. I meant the C-strings not the stl string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, realize that concatenating strings as std::string::operator+() and [std::string::operator+=()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) do, is a conceptually different operation from addition.

The things you're asking about "adding" are C-style strings, which come from C, so C++ supports them. There is no operator overloading in C.

A C-style string is just a pointer to an array of characters in memory, which is (hopefully) terminated by a NULL character `'\0'`. A `char *` may point to a C-string, or it may not. You have to manage the memory yourself. The memory may be allocated statically, and there may be only enough room for the characters you put there to start with, such as when you define a string `char myString[] = "blah";`. There are no built-in, automatic memory reallocation mechanisms, so even if such a concatenation function were defined, it couldn't guarantee that there would be room for whatever you want to append to a string in the target buffer.

By contrast, in C++, std::string is a class that dynamically allocates memory as needed. std::string objects are always std::strings; they don't point to other things. Concatenation operators are defined (+, +=), and they handle memory (re)allocation for you.

...So now you know the two main types of strings used in C++, so you can do some further research on "C-style strings" or "C strings"<sup>1</sup>; and std::string, which is a "C++ string". Maybe start at Wikipedia: [String (C++)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_%28C%2B%2B%29).

---

<sup>1</sup> FYI, "C-String" is also the name of a type of revealing clothing, so you may get some [NSFW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_safe_for_work) search results mixed in using that term.

Comment: [Ed: this should be below your "That helps..." comment.] It's not whether you `#include <string>` or `<string.h>`, it's how you declare the variable. `char var[] = "stuff";` or `char *var = "stuff";` are C strings. `std::string var = "stuff";` is a C++ string. A C++ string may be automatically created from a C string though, like if you pass a C string as a parameter to a function that takes a `std::string`.

Comment: That helps. Thank you. I have a question. When we declare a string variable w/o including the library, it means we are using the C-Strings, right? (which is const char []) Also, you said a char* may point to a string which means it can either point to an array of characters or just one character, right?

Comment: "a char* may point to...an array of characters or just one character, right?" Yes. Or just a location in memory, or an array of bytes (since char is a single byte in width on most platforms, though the stdint type uint8_t is often a better fit for that)...

Comment: That is if we explicitly use the word string, we are using the C++ string?

Comment: In C++ code, if you have a `using namespace std;` or `using std::string;` somewhere, then yes, `string` means `std::string` means C++ string object. In English speaking *about* C++, or pseudocode, "string" is not necessarily clear, so it's good to specify std::string or C style string.

Comment: Also, in char [] name, name acts as a constant pointer which can't be modified, and in char * name, the value name points to can't be modified?

Comment: When you say "The memory may be allocated statically,", you mean, we can, if we want, dynamically allocate memory, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91278/discussion-between-cp-engr-and-sta-ck-ov).